# Ubuntu 16.04 Unable to save ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeOnSaveBuild/SublimeOnSaveBuild.sublime-settings

Tags: sublimetext3

Getting this error on pressing **ctrl + s** in **sublime version 3.1.1**

`Unable to save ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeOnSaveBuild/SublimeOnSaveBuild.sublime-settings
Error: No such file or directory`e

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 Operating System.

`https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt` for sublime installation

Followed the below procedure

ctrl + shift + p to open Package Control -> Select Install Package
Install Dependencies through Package Control
**Sublime​On​Save​Build**

**Preferences -> Package Settings -> Sublime​On​Save​Build -> Settings - User**

```
{
   "filename_filter": "\\.(css|js|jsx|json|sass|less|scss)$",
   "build_on_save": 1
}
```

**Preferences -> Package Settings -> Sublime​On​Save​Build -> Settings - Default**

```
{
    "filename_filter": "\\.(css|js|sass|less|scss)$",
    "build_on_save": 1
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to save the default settings, you can't; they're the default and probably packed up. If you're trying to save the user settings and that's the path you're getting in the error, the package is broken; your user settings should be in the `User` package.

Comment: @OdatNurd so what changes should i do

Comment: The appropriate procedure is to modify and save the `User` settings; anything you put in there overrides the settings in the `Default`.

Comment: thanks @OdatNurd worked...